# How to print each individual command of a chained command line in a Dockerfile as they execute during build?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, dockerfile

In a `Dockerfile` I chain multiple commands into a single `RUN`, as is common practice:

```
RUN cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && ...
```

When calling `docker build`, it prints the entire line `cmd1 && cmd2 && ...` and then executes it. This is fine when everything works; however, when an error message happens, it is sometimes not clear which command printed it.

Is there a way to print the different commands as they are executed, so that the origin of errors becomes obvious?

I am looking for solutions for both linux and windows containers.

Comment: The usual approach is to split the `RUN` line into several, especially while you're debugging it.  There are few technical reasons you _need_ to have commands combined into a single `RUN` line, splitting and recombining them is usually harmless.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
FROM debian
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echoRun(){ echo "$@"; "$@"; } &&\
    echoRun date &&\
    echoRun sleep 2 &&\
    echoRun false &&\
    echoRun date
```

then build with :

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t test .
```

I'm not sure about Windows container though.